# Web Service between Visual Basic 2010 and Android

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, wifi, android-wifi

i am making a project to help restaurant order system.. so the cashier using application build in visual basic 2010, and the waiter/waitress will use android as a Menu Book and they will sent data order to the server.

my problem is : i want to transfer my data which in database in visual basic (.mdf) to gadget android via wifi. so far, i was able to transfer string from android to VB 2010 via TCP socket.

please help to about the concept or best way to transfer database via wifi, a book / reference or some tutorial with a simple code will good :)

database in visual basic and in Android have the same structure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a local web service and use ksoap 2 library to do that. Its my opinion for the best way..

and here is the tutorial http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

Comment: thanks for your reference.. but do you know something about json? i think i will build jason object for transfer my database data to Android..

Comment: I know json but don't have experience as much as web services. so I prefer web services. I would say it comes down to which platform you are most comfortable with.